# How to mutate data in R to wrap replicates together

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

I have this data

```r
df <- structure(list(
  Replicate = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), 
  VF = c(2, 2, 1.7, 1.95), 
  VI = c(2.15, 2.05, 1.7, 2.2)), 
row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

How can I mutate this data to have both samples (VI and VF) with replicates in columns? I want `VF_Rep1 VF_Rep3 VI_Rep1 VI_Rep3` as my new columns.

Comment: Do you need `df %>% gather(key, val, VF:VI) %>% group_by(Replicate, key) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% unite(RepK, key, Replicate) %>% spread(RepK, val)`

Comment: @akrun This works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `gather` the 'VF', 'VI' columns to 'long' format, then create a sequence grouped by 'Replicate', 'key', and `spread` it back to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(key, val, VF:VI) %>% 
  group_by(Replicate = paste0("Rep", Replicate), key) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  unite(RepK, key, Replicate) %>% 
  spread(RepK, val)
```